# In CMake how to use `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)` when one of the dependencies is a framework

Tags: cmake

The below minimal example works when the runtime dependent library is a normal library,

```
project(sample)
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)

add_executable(mytest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest Foo)
set_target_properties(mytest PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/")
install(TARGETS mytest RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(
  CODE "file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES EXECUTABLES \$<TARGET_FILE:mytest> RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR DEPS)\n \"
         foreach(DEP \${DEPS})\n \
           file(INSTALL \${DEPS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)\n \
         endforeach()")
```

After `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp ..`, `make install`, `/tmp/bin/mytest` runs perfectly, however I am having difficulties to make this work if the runtime dependent library is a framework, for example,

```
project(sample)
add_library(Foo SHARED foo.cpp foo.h)
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES FRAMEWORK TRUE PUBLIC_HEADER "foo.h")

add_executable(mytest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest Foo)
set_target_properties(mytest PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/")
install(TARGETS mytest RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(
  CODE "file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES EXECUTABLES \$<TARGET_FILE:mytest> RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR DEPS)\n \"
         foreach(DEP \${DEPS})\n \
           file(INSTALL \${DEPS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)\n \
         endforeach()")
```

After `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp ..`, `make install`, `/tmp/bin/mytest` failed with `dyld Library not loaded: @rpath/Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo`, after investigation, I realized it's because only `Foo` is copied to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin`, but what needs to happen is the entire framework `Foo.framework/Versions/A/Foo` to be copied to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin`. How can I modify the `install CODE` block so that it detects if the dependency is a framework it copies the whole framework, and if the dependency is not a framework, it copies that library itself? The cmake function that can be used inside the `install CODE` block seems to be very limited.